# I'm not able to assign "<div id=<%=rs.getString(1)%>">

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm retrieving building name from database and I have to assign div id as building name.

This is the code block having the issue

```
  while(rs.next())
                            {
                                %>
                                <div id="<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
                                <%
                                out.println(rs.getString(1));

                                %>
                                </div>
                                <%
                            }
```

Above I assigned div id by using rs.getString(1).
But It shows error

```
  <%
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/crm","root","");
                    Statement st = con.createStatement() ;
                    ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("select name from building where 1") ;
                    rs.last();
                    int count=rs.getRow();

                    if(count>0)
                    {
                        rs.beforeFirst();
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            %>
                            <div id="<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
                            <%
                            out.println(rs.getString(1));

                            %>
                            </div>
                            <%
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        out.print("No Buildings Added Yet");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    out.print(e);
                }

                %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It is no good architecture to use sql directly in the view. Learn about 3tier architecture.

Comment: guessing from what i see in the code your getting an sql exception ? Incorrect syntax near '1' ?

Comment: Database connectivity is working fine. Here what I need is I want to give id for div tag. So I made the code like: <div id="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"></div>. Is there any other way to assign the id retrieved value into the <div> tag

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague but I think I know what is going on.

You have created a "forward only" Statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement--

You must create a statement that is TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE and CONCUR_READ_ONLY (ideally) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: db connection is ok and i got that value which is retrieved from db. but the problem Im facing is i cant assign that retrieved value as id in div tag

Comment: If you are getting an exception blown out in the page or in the logs please post it otherwise this question will be flagged and closed as too vague or "debug this for me"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSTL tags (`<c:set>` or `<c:out>`).

```
<c:set var = "id" scope = "session" value = "<%=rs.getString(1)%>"/>
```

or

```
<c:out value = "<%=rs.getString(1)%>"/>
```

Put it in your code instead of "<%=rs.getString(1)%>" and give it a run.